# Parameters for buy order on BTC-E

Tags: api, bots

Using the BTC-E API 'm getting an error of `You incorrectly entered one of fields.` when I post this as the data in a buy order.

```
{'pair': 'btc_usd', 'amount': 0.1, 'rate': 44.7084704, 'type': 'buy', 'method': 'Trade'}
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved. The error is caused by too many decimal places in the `rate` parameter. It would be good if the API returned a more informative error message though.

There is an API call to find the correct maximum number of places, as well as the minimum order for each currency pair. `https://btc-e.com/api/3/info` returns a list of currencies and information. The [documentation](https://btc-e.com/api/3/documentation#info) is in Russian but translates easily with Google Translate.

Comment: got this error too. looks like correct number of decimal places is 5 or 6 (I tested on LTC)